# prestashop (php / SESSION variables ) how to store variables from a form and use them in if / else commands

Tags: php, forms, variables, smarty, prestashop

On prestashop 1.5 what i am trying to do is to initally create a form on the right hand side that asks customers

Do you want to:

(1) Display price with tax
(2) Display price without tax

Then there answer is stored in a smarty session variable. (i think thats the best way to do it?)

Then on the product.tpl page, there would be if, else commands

if session variable 'displaytax'

prices with tax

if session variable 'displaynotax'

price without tax

else
end if

Can anybody please help with code to:

(1) Initially create this simple form and store the session variable?
(2) To bring back the session variable so you can use it in the if else statement?

Many thanks for taking the time to look

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In prestashop 1.5, global are deprecated.

To set something in the cookie :

In a controller :

```
$this->context->cookie->__set($key,$value);
```

Other file :

```
$context = Context::getContext();
$context->cookie->__set($key,$value);
```

You can access to your value with :

In a controller

```
$this->context->cookie->key
```

Other file :

```
$context = Context::getContext();
$context->cookie->key;
```

Prestashop doesn't use the $_SESSSION, so you can't access to `$smarty.session.key`

You have to assign your variable to smarty

In a controller :

```
$this->context->smarty->assign(array('key' => $this->context->cookie->key));
```

Other file :

```
$context = Context::getContext();
$context->smarty->assign(array('key' => $context->cookie->key));
```

Comment: Shouldn't this line :

`$context->smarty->assign(array('key' => $context->cookie->key));`

Look like this :

`$context->smarty->assign(array($key => $context->cookie->key));`